# Making a countDownTimer pause on button presses

Tags: java, android, button, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a basic app where I can press a button to start a countdown, and the text on that same button changes between "START", "PAUSE", or "RESUME" depending on which state the button was in when pressed. Currently the pressing the button does nothing and I'm not sure why.

The button starts out with the text "start"

This is the code for the button listener in onCreate()

None of the 'if' statements seem to ever be true, even though the starting text on the button is "start"

```
clockText = findViewById(R.id.timer);    
final Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.timerBtn);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(clockText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("resume")) {
                startTimer(milliLeft);
                clock.start();
                startButton.setText("resume");
            }
            else if(clockText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("pause")){
                clock.cancel();
                clockText.setText(formatTime);
                startButton.setText("resume");
            }
            else if(clockText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("start")){
                startTimer(30000);
                startButton.setText("pause");
                clock.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the startTimer() method,

```
public int sec,min,fracSec;
public String formatTime;
public TextView clockText;
public CountDownTimer clock;
public long milliLeft;
public void startTimer(long time) {
    clock = new CountDownTimer(time, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



                milliLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                min = (int) Math.floor(millisUntilFinished / 60000);
                sec = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                fracSec = ((int) millisUntilFinished - sec * 1000) / 100;
                formatTime = min + ":" + sec + ":" + fracSec;
                clockText.setText(formatTime);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            clockText.setText("Finished");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are checking the text value of the wrong view. You are checking the text value of the clockText instead of the startButton, which is the view you are setting the text values of "resume", "pause","start" on. You need to change the code to:

```
clockText = findViewById(R.id.timer);    
final Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.timerBtn);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(startButton.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("resume")) {
                startTimer(milliLeft);
                clock.start();
                startButton.setText("resume");
            }
            else if(startButton.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("pause")){
                clock.cancel();
                clockText.setText(formatTime);
                startButton.setText("resume");
            }
            else if(startButton.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("start")){
                startTimer(30000);
                startButton.setText("pause");
                clock.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks guess I just needed another set of eyes to catch something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing 'clockText':

```
if(clockText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("resume"))
```

But you are setting the value in your button :

```
startButton.setText("resume");
```

Change your conditional

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, not sure how I didn't notice that but thanks!